# How to create and edit recurring to-do tasks

Tags: 8.0, calendars, exchange, outlook

On my iPhone I've been using the Reminders app quite a lot which syncs with my Live account. There I can create tasks and set them to repeat.

I have now moved to Windows Phone (Lumia 1020) and although I can find the tasks in the calendar/to-do I see no way of editing or creating recurring tasks. Am i missing something, or is the feature simply not there?

If not there, any recommendations? Or do I simply have to use outlook.com/webmail to create those tasks?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that feature is currently not available. You could always try third party applications. I use an app called [TinyDo](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/tinydo/ea0f699d-f6c0-4008-a228-8d9d1974c2c6).

You are able to create categories for tasks. Which is very handy if you need to be able to sort your tasks (work, school, home, etc.) It stays very true to the Metro design language, however it does not have notifications of tasks.

Comment: Would need to sync with exchange, which TinyDo doesn't do as far as I can see :/

Comment: Ya, unfortunately it doesn't. :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to make to-do task recurring. But you could add normal task to a calendar and set its occurrence to every day, weekdays, every Monday etc.